# Folds implementation in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, refactoring, fold

I am having LOTS of problem trying to understand folds implementation on Haskell. I need to have two functions using fold that have this output

```
> runLengthEncode "aaaaaaabbb"
[(7,'a'),(3,'b')]
> runLengthDecode [(1,'h'), (5,'i')]
"hiiiii"
```

So what I did is to write the function first as I would do with pattern matching (they work), but now I do not know how to "translate" that using either fold left or fold right.

```
runLengthEncode :: String -> [(Int,Char)]
runLengthEncode [] = []
runLengthEncode (x:xs) = runLengthEncode 1 x xs
    where
        runLengthEncode n x [] = [(n,x)]
        runLengthEncode n x (y:ys) | x == y = runLengthEncode (n + 1) y ys
                                   | otherwise = (n,x) : runLengthEncode 1 y ys

runLengthDecode :: [(Int,Char)] -> String
runLengthDecode [] = []
runLengthDecode ((a,b):xs) = replicate a b ++ (runLengthDecode xs)
```

Comment: You should post your attempt at using folds, and explain the issues you met.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation. ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135493/172601))

Comment: Have you had a chance to look into the links I provided in the above comment? By not accepting answers you keep the questions open, signal to the community that those questions are still unresolved. Are they, still? If so, why no follow-up questions or requests for clarification in the comments?

Answer (score 8):

Think of a fold as taking a list of terms:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

and adding an initial value `zz` and binary operator `<+>` between the terms:

```
foldl (<+>) zz [a,b,c,d] = (((zz <+> a) <+> b) <+> c) <+> d
foldr (<+>) zz [a,b,c,d] = a <+> (b <+> (c <+> (d <+> zz)))
```

Note that the initial value is also the value the fold will have when applied to an empty list, so that's usually easy to figure out.  The hard part is defining the appropriate binary operator.

So, to express `runLengthEncode` as right fold, you need:

```
'a' <+> ('a' <+> ('a' <+> ('b' <+> zz))) = [(3,'a'),(1,'b')]
```

for an operator `<+>` and some initial value `zz`.

We can easily "solve" for `zz` because we know that `runLengthEncode [] = []`, so `zz = []`.  We need to define `<+>` so that it satifies equations derived from the example above (working right to left) like:

```
'b' <+> [] = [(1, 'b')]
'a' <+> [(1, 'b')] = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
'a' <+> [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b')] = [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
'a' <+> [(2, 'a'), (1, 'b')] = [(3, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

Defining such an operator is actually pretty easy:

```
(<+>) :: Char -> [(Int, Char)] -> [(Int, Char)]
x <+> ((n, y) : rest) | x == y = ((n+1), y) : rest
x <+> rest                     = (1, x) : rest
```

so we get:

```
runLengthEncode' :: String -> [(Int,Char)]
runLengthEncode' = foldr (<+>) []
```

Try doing this with a left fold, too:

```
(((zz + 'a') <+> 'a') <+> 'a') <+> 'b' =>  [(3,'a'),(1,'b')]
```

You'll find that when it comes time to define `<+>`, you have to inspect the *last* element of the current RLE instead of the first.  It can be done, of course, but it's slightly less natural, which is why I used a right fold above.

For `runLengthDecode`, it's the same business:

```
(1, 'h') <+> ((5, 'i') <+> zz) = "hiiiii"
```

Again, determine what `zz` should be.  Then, figure out how you write a binary operator to solve:

```
(5, 'i') <+> zz = "iiiii"
(1, 'h') <+> "iiiii" = "hiiiii"
```

**Spoilers follow...**

Of course, you don't actually need to use an operator syntax, so a full solution would look like:

```
runLengthEncode'' :: String -> [(Int,Char)]
runLengthEncode'' = foldr step []
  where step x ((n, y) : rest) | x == y = ((n+1), y) : rest
        step x rest                     = (1, x) : rest

runLengthDecode'' :: [(Int,Char)] -> String
runLengthDecode'' = foldr step ""
  where step (n, x) str = replicate n x ++ str
```

Comment: *Inductive programming FTW!* --- "have to inspect the last element of the current RLE" last *is* first, just looking in the *reversed* direction... :)